# Thousands of incoming SSH connection attempts despite firewall lockdown

Tags: ssh, iptables, ufw

So my server is getting slammed with thousands of SSH login attempts. Fail2ban is catching and banning them - but my inbox it's worrying me and it filling up inbox with alerts. Here's a sample of what I'm seeing:

```
May 28 15:26:09 sshd[4908]: input_userauth_request: invalid user test [preauth]
May 28 15:26:09 sshd[4908]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
May 28 15:26:09 sshd[4908]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<<SNIPIP>>
May 28 15:26:11 sshd[4908]: Failed password for invalid user test from <<SNIPIP>> port 41344 ssh2
May 28 15:26:11 sshd[4908]: Received disconnect from <<SNIPIP>> port 41344:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
May 28 15:26:11 sshd[4908]: Disconnected from <<SNIPIP>> port 41344 [preauth]
```

What's interesting is when I attempt to connect using something like:
`ssh test@myserverip -p 41344`

my connection attempt eventually times out and I see no entry in auth.log - which is what I would expect to happen given I've locked the machine firewall down via UFW: (sidenote: I'm already running ssh on a non standard port)

```
ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY IN     144.202.55.196
Anywhere                   DENY IN     188.53.140.190
Anywhere                   DENY IN     185.50.197.159
Anywhere                   DENY IN     206.189.197.133
Anywhere                   DENY IN     61.175.121.73
Anywhere                   DENY IN     8.30.124.149
Anywhere                   DENY IN     193.105.134.45
Anywhere                   DENY IN     139.129.14.230
Anywhere                   DENY IN     37.247.96.111
22                         DENY IN     Anywhere
2200/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2246                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2812                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2247/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
19999/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
82/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
2200/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2246 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2812 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2247/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
19999/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
82/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

So my main question is, how is it possible that someone is even getting a chance to attempt a login on port 41344 when I can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the source port of the connection on the remote end. The connection is made to port 22 on your side (or whatever your SSH daemon is listening on).

Every network socket consists of a source address and port and a destination address and port. The source port is randomly selected by the originating OS.

Comment: aha - of course! I'm an idiot - thanks so much Sven :)